# Typescript object literal

Tags: typescript, object, interface, literals, behavior

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html has this example:

```
interface LabeledValue {
  label: string;
}

function printLabel(labeledObj: LabeledValue) {
  console.log(labeledObj.label);
}

let myObj = { size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object" };
printLabel(myObj);
```

But if I pass an object literal to printLabel, instead of myObj, like so:

```
printLabel({ size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object" })
```

then  I get an error

```
>  error TS2345: Argument of type '{ size: number; label: string; }' is
> not assignable to parameter of type 'LabeledValue'.   Object literal
> may only specify known properties, and 'size' does not exist in type
> 'LabeledValue'.
> 
> 11 printLabel({ size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object" });
```

Why is this? Why is this behavior different ?

Comment: [Excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)

Comment: or possibly because `let myObj` gets assigned the type `any`, hence passes compilation.

Comment: It's *most definitely* not that. The implicit type for `myObj` would be `{size: number, label: string}`. This matches structurally the `LabeledValue` interface and since you're not *directly* passing an object literal, no excess property check is performed in that case. The check is performed only when *directly* using an object literal - you can observe it if you do `let myObj: LabeledValue`

Comment: understood. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz

Answer (score 0):

As { size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object" } is a object literal.

When it comes to whether a ts object literal is assignable to another , it will compare the whole properties. Here, label is not acceptable.